# How to run native code on recieving sms android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am developing an android app completely native using only c++.

But I am not able to find a way to run some native code ,when a sms arrives. In java I can do it through broadcast receiver .But not able to find any method for ndk.

Or any suggestion how can i use broadcast receivers to run native code

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java BroadcastReceiver and have it call a native method to do all the work.  There's no benefit in not doing it the easy way just to claim "no Java".